# Does Thread.sleep() make the execution to cease for accurate an interval

Tags: java

Here is my code

```
try{

  System.out.println("Before");
  thread.sleep(10000);//sleep for 10000 ms
  System.out.println("After");

}
catch(ItrerruptedException ie){
//If this thread was intrrupted by nother thread 
}
```

I just want to know whether the thread will sleep for exaclty 10 seconds and then print `After` or there is some delay?

Comment: For some value for "exactly", yes. It can certainly deviate on the nanosecond and millisecond level between tries.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by exactly and some delay. Compared to the silicon eon that is ten seconds, negligible I should think, like nanoseconds unless some other ill behaved process is hogging the CPU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the javadocs: `Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers.` Which means it will sleep for at least 10 seconds. It may sleep longer if the scheduler decides to not let it run after the 10 seconds is over. 
Which may happen if more concurrent threads are in the runnable pool at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

A non realtime scheduler won't guarantee timing.

If you are doing some kind of hardware communication that really relies on timing, you should probably use [RTSJ](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/realtime/index.jsp).

If you are doing something each x milliseconds, you could use a [TimeTask](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=54) that will perform slightly better.

Answer (score 2):

It will sleep for at least 10 seconds, and wake shortly after (unless interrupted).  How soon after depends on the OS and the load on the machine.

Comment: So u mean to say tht there is no guarantee that 'After' will be printed after exact 10 seconds...?

Comment: For scheduling **guarantees** you need a real time OS. There is Real Time Java as well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_time_Java

Answer (score 0):

It's more or less random because your OS task scheduler is usually not required to give your process all the attention it wants. Usually, you will not be able to sleep for very small amounts of time (for example, `Thread.sleep(5)` might resume your process later than 5 ms after the call), but as you increase the sleep time, the relative precision increases.

If you can tolerate some leeway, `Thread.sleep(10000)` will usually sleep for an amount of time that's close enough to 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I would say unless you have lots of threads running it's pretty close to exact. If you have several threads then it's a competition.

Answer (score 0):

The overhead of the thread from sleep to running is very low.